# Fast Scan stdin to get integer not working

Tags: c++

I have made this function in c++ to read inputs from `stdin` faster than `cin` for using in competitive programming judges.

```
inline int VReadNumber() {
 int n = 0;
 int ch = getchar_unlocked();

 while(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
  n = (n<<3) + (n<<1) + ch - '0';
  ch = getchar_unlocked();
 }

 return n; }
```

It works perfectly if all inputs are given without line breaks like

```
2
40 40
80 
5
1 2 3 4 5
10
```

But it doesn't do well with line breaks in the inputs like

```
2
40 40
80 

5
1 2 3 4 5
10
```

and only reads values till the line break, here ***until 80***.

How can i make this work with line breaks? Also a usage example would be greatly appreciated.

Is it worth using this with all its "nuances" instead of `scanf` and such?

Comment: *...it doesn't do well with line breaks*... What does that mean? What goes wrong?

Comment: Do you think there are compilers today that would not optimize `n*10` into `(n<<3) + (n<<1)` on platforms where it gives you an advantage in speed?

Comment: it  gives me zeroes instead of reading the number after the line break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because an empty line means two consecutive non-digit (`\n`) characters. Your code can handle only one. Add another loop for consuming whitespace, ideally at the beginning of the function and leave the last non-digit character in the buffer.

Comment: thanks for answering, please elaborate on how to do this and also give the "corrected version" if possible